# Django allauth not rendering appropriate model and field names for username field

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am getting this rendered from django-allauth for unique username check.

```
%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.
```

A quick search online shows the email error was resolved and can be overridden with:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
   # Overrides default adapter
   def __init__(self, request=None):
        super(CustomAccountAdapter, self).__init__(request)
        self.error_messages['email_taken'] = _('A user is already registered with this e-mail address.')
```

However, overriding the adapter this way isn't working for username. Can anyone please help with this, this is the only thing preventing me from going live right now...

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Do you want to test if a user email is already registered in Django ? What is this : "%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists." ?? An error message or what ?

Comment: If a username already exists, a user email renders properly, however, user name errors don't. Searched all tickets on github the solutions provided are related to those with email fields only, not username.

Comment: did you find a solution? Also having same issue.